# Communicate between Android and ROS threads

Tags: ros, c++, multithreading, java, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a simple Java class that launch a thread containing a ROS node

```
public class ROSThread implements Runnable {
private Thread m_thread;

public ROSThread() {
    this.m_thread = new Thread(this);
}

public void rosrun(){
    m_thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // start your classic ROS node (spin()) in a dedicated thread
    startROSNode();
}

//load C/C++ shared library
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("ros_main");
}
private native void startROSNode();
}
```

Which is launched in the Activity class

```
ROSThread rosThread = new ROSThread();
rosThread.rosrun();
```

In this activity, I would like to indicate to my ROS nod that it needs to publish something.
Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262443/communicate-between-android-and-ros-threads/) by [TristanKpka](https://answers.ros.org/users/30075/tristankpka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@TristanKpka take a look at this post: https://answers.ros.org/question/272979/rosjava-publishing-to-a-topic-based-on-user-input-button/.

You need to create a node that can publish something "on demand", and the call that method whenever you want.

Unless you need a package that was already written in Cpp, I would just use the regular nodes provided by `rosjava`. Those will give you the functionality you need to publish messages.

A bit late, but hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0